# Executing a terminal command from Java without any change

Tags: java, node.js, linux, bash, shell

I'm working on a project where I'm obliged to call NodeJS script from SpringBoot microservice, I've tried to do this by executing a terminal command from Java programmaticaly, console is not showing any errors, but the command doesn't really execute (no changes), otherwise I've tried to execute the same command from the same directory on terminal and it works perfectly, I've also checked all permissions for possible accessed files to reading and writing, but still having the same problem...
Here is my method's code :

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/injectlps",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void injectLPSWithConfig(@PathParam(value="json") String json) {
        getJSONFile(json);
        try {
            File directory=new File(new File("./scripts/").getCanonicalPath());
            System.out.println(directory.getPath());
            ProcessBuilder p=new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash","-c","npx ts-node serverMain.ts \"../tmp/\" \"lps.json\"");
            p.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT);
            p.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
            p.directory(directory);
            Process pr=p.start();
            pr.waitFor();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've tried to put the command on a .sh script and launching it with ProcessBuilder, but as before there are no changes, and the same script works as well when I run it from terminal.

Comment: Please read the processes error stream and let us know whether there are any error messages. Also you should create your `scripts` directory -- it may not exists.

Comment: The script directory already exists, the processes error stream shows `/bin/bash: npx: not found` @tgdavies

Comment: So you need to make sure that `npx` is on your PATH

Comment: Note 'terminal' never runs anything; normally when you type a command in a terminal window it is a shell process, like bash, that gets that command and executes it by running something. In the _shell_ where this works do `ps` to confirm if your shell is in fact bash and not something else, and `type npx` to see whether that is actually an alias or function, or if it is a 'real' executable (a file in a directory in your $PATH)